# Compound SELECT query postgreSQL / postGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, psql

Probaby a simple syntax issue but I have this postGIS query I'd like to run on a single table:

```
SELECT 
    ST_Overlaps(g1.geom,g2.geom) AS asr_01
FROM 
    ch03.my_polygons g1, ch03.my_polygons g2
WHERE 
    g1.agent_type = 0 AND g2.agent_type != 0 AND g1.sim_time = 0.0
```

which works as expected, but I'd like to also select an adjacent column such as this

```
SELECT 
    agent_id 
FROM 
    ch03.my_polygons
WHERE 
    agent_type != 0
```

which also works fine but how do I combine these? Tried this...

```
SELECT 
    agent_id,
    ST_Overlaps(g1.geom,g2.geom) AS asr_01
FROM 
    ch03.my_polygons,
    ch03.my_polygons g1, ch03.my_polygons g2 
WHERE
    agent_type != 0,
    g1.agent_type = 0 AND g2.agent_type != 0 AND g1.sim_time = 0.0
```

Possible? Another way to get around this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out with combining the use of the variables...

```
SELECT 
    g2.agent_id,
    ST_Overlaps(g1.geom,g2.geom) AS asr_01
FROM 
    ch03.my_polygons g1, ch03.my_polygons g2 
WHERE
    g1.agent_type = 0 AND g2.agent_type != 0 AND g1.sim_time = 0.0
```